# Options -Indexes not working in .htaccess file in Docker container

Tags: apache, .htaccess, docker

I have the following .htaccess file used in the web home of Apache2 in a Docker container:

```
# allows HTML files to be interpretted as PHP files
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

# allows redirect to *.html files without using the extension
# e.g., http://example.com/foo will show http://example.com/foo.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options All
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    #RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
    RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# causes redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

# environament variables
SetEnv DBL "mysql:dbname=roars;host=foo;port=3306"
SetEnv DB_USER "bar"
SetEnv DB_PASS "glorp"
```

The `Options -Indexes` directive is not keeping us from being able to view directories. All of the other directives work properly and when I use this .htaccess file outside of a Docker container it works appropriately by disallowing the viewing of a directory.

Have I done something wrong, or is this particular to Docker containers?

Comment: Are you sure this htaccess is being read?

Comment: Yes, because *as stated* all of the other directives work properly @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue in the default configuration file for Apache2 in the Docker container:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName dev.f0o.com
    DocumentRoot /home/foo/src/www-server/

    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /home/foo/src/www-server/>
    # allow .htaccess overrides to work
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex login.html index.html index.php
</Directory>

# this matches a link to any device directory to the physical webui directory
#AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/css/(.*)$ /home/foo/src/www-server/static/css/$2
#AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/fonts/(.*)$ /home/foo/src/www-server/static/fonts/$2
#AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/images/(.*)$ /home/foo/src/www-server/static/images/$2
#AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/lib/(.*)$ /home/foo/src/www-server/static/lib/$2
#AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/scripts/(.*)$ /home/foo/src/www-server/static/scripts/$2

AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/(.*)$ /home/foo/src/www-server/client/$2


<Directory /home/foo/src/www-server/client>
    DirectoryIndex home.html
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Solution 1** - The issue was first noticed in `/home/foo/src/www-server/client` which has its own specific set of overrides at the end of the default configuration file. the directory listing was allowed because `Options` is set to `All`. Changing it to `Options -Indexes` fixed the issue.

---

**Solution 2** - As an experiment I commented out the line starting with `Options` and the results were what I wanted, likely because the .htaccess file was allowed to perform its job without conflict from the default configuration file.

---

Because I am not, typically, a person who configures web servers I am sure there might be better ways to solve the issue given the set of known's we have now. Those with more expertise in Apache web server configuration may have more elegant solutions.